# Table Cell colors have white gaps between them

Tags: tables, color, tabularx, multirow, colortbl

I'm trying to set up a table for some results I got for some experiments.

I was trying to recreate this table in my latex document (not exactly, but the general look of it).
[image: Table with multicolumns and many cell colors]

I'm 99% on the way there, however the cell colors look off. There's vertical white gaps between the colored cells

[image: Table with multicolumns and many cell colors, in latex. There is white vertical gaps between the colored cells.]

Here is the code for my latex table:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Adjust the vertical padding here
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Architecture Performances}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|} % Add vertical lines
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{greyheader}Architecture} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{greenheader}Accuracy} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{blueheader}Precision} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{yellowheader}Recall} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{orangeheader}F1 Scores} \\
\cline{2-9}
 & \cellcolor{greenheader}TL & \cellcolor{greenheader}PT & \cellcolor{blueheader}TL & \cellcolor{blueheader}PT & \cellcolor{yellowheader}TL & \cellcolor{yellowheader}PT & \cellcolor{orangeheader}TL & \cellcolor{orangeheader}PT \\
\hline
\cellcolor{greybody}VGG16 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.8182 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.7727 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.8000 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.7500 & \cellcolor{yellowbody}0.8000 & \cellcolor{yellowbody}0.7500 & \cellcolor{orangebody}0.8000 & \cellcolor{orangebody}0.7500 \\
\cellcolor{greybody}VGG19 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.7273 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.7955 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.8000 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.7619 &\cellcolor{yellowbody}0.6000 & \cellcolor{yellowbody}0.8000 & \cellcolor{orangebody}0.6667 & \cellcolor{orangebody}0.7805 \\
\cellcolor{greybody}ResNet50 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.8409 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.7045 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.8824 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.7059 & \cellcolor{yellowbody}0.7500 & \cellcolor{yellowbody}0.6000 & \cellcolor{orangebody}0.8108 & \cellcolor{orangebody}0.6486 \\
\cellcolor{greybody}ResNet152 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.8182 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.6591 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.9286 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.6316 & \cellcolor{yellowbody}0.6500 & \cellcolor{yellowbody}0.6000 & \cellcolor{orangebody}0.7647 &\cellcolor{orangebody} 0.6154 \\
\cellcolor{greybody}DenseNet121 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.8182 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.8409 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.8750 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.7826 & \cellcolor{yellowbody}0.7000 & \cellcolor{yellowbody}0.9000 & \cellcolor{orangebody}0.7778 & \cellcolor{orangebody}0.8372 \\
\cellcolor{greybody}DenseNet201 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.8636 & \cellcolor{greenbody}0.7955 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.8889 & \cellcolor{bluebody}0.7619 & \cellcolor{yellowbody}0.8000 & \cellcolor{yellowbody}0.8000 & \cellcolor{orangebody}0.8421 & \cellcolor{orangebody}0.7805 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

and, since having the individual cell colors is a massive eyesore, here's the same table but with no cell colors

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Adjust the vertical padding here
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Architecture Performances}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|} % Add vertical lines
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Architecture} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Accuracy} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Precision} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Recall} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{F1 Scores} \\
\cline{2-9}
 & TL & PT & TL & PT & TL & PT & TL & PT \\
\hline
VGG16 & 0.8182 & 0.7727 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 \\
VGG19 & 0.7273 & 0.7955 & 0.8000 & 0.7619 & 0.6000 & 0.8000 & 0.6667 & 0.7805 \\
ResNet50 & 0.8409 & 0.7045 & 0.8824 & 0.7059 & 0.7500 & 0.6000 & 0.8108 & 0.6486 \\
ResNet152 & 0.8182 & 0.6591 & 0.9286 & 0.6316 & 0.6500 & 0.6000 & 0.7647 & 0.6154 \\
DenseNet121 & 0.8182 & 0.8409 & 0.8750 & 0.7826 & 0.7000 & 0.9000 & 0.7778 & 0.8372 \\
DenseNet201 & 0.8636 & 0.7955 & 0.8889 & 0.7619 & 0.8000 & 0.8000 & 0.8421 & 0.7805 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Have a look at the tabularray package.

Comment: Colours bleed a lot in regular tables, it is why I use `nicematrix`, I am not familiar with `tabularray` package recommended by samcarter but if you want colours in your tables then it is difficult with `tabularx` so is worth looking at those although someone will probably answer with good alternatives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution using the `tabularray` package (`Q[co=1]` is synonym for the `X` column type):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor, tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Architecture Performances}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = { l *{8}{ Q[si={table-format=1.4},c,co=1] } },
    row{1,2} = {guard},
    stretch = 1.5,
    % lines
    vline{1} = {2-Z}{},
    vline{2-Z} = {1-Z}{},
    hline{1} = {2-Z}{},
    hline{2,3,Z} = {1-Z}{},
    % cell spans
    cell{1}{2,4,6,8} = {c=2}{c},
    % colors
    cell{2}{1} = {}{gray8},
    cell{1-2}{2-3} = {}{green8},
    cell{1-2}{4-5} = {}{blue8},
    cell{1-2}{6-7} = {}{yellow8},
    cell{1-2}{8-9} = {}{brown8},
    cell{3-Z}{1} = {}{gray9},
    cell{3-Z}{2-3} = {}{green9},
    cell{3-Z}{4-5} = {}{blue9},
    cell{3-Z}{6-7} = {}{yellow9},
    cell{3-Z}{8-9} = {}{brown9},
}
 & Accuracy & & Precision & & Recall & & F1 Scores & \\
Architecture & TL & PT & TL & PT & TL & PT & TL & PT \\
VGG16 & 0.8182 & 0.7727 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 \\
VGG19 & 0.7273 & 0.7955 & 0.8000 & 0.7619 & 0.6000 & 0.8000 & 0.6667 & 0.7805 \\
ResNet50 & 0.8409 & 0.7045 & 0.8824 & 0.7059 & 0.7500 & 0.6000 & 0.8108 & 0.6486 \\
ResNet152 & 0.8182 & 0.6591 & 0.9286 & 0.6316 & 0.6500 & 0.6000 & 0.7647 & 0.6154 \\
DenseNet121 & 0.8182 & 0.8409 & 0.8750 & 0.7826 & 0.7000 & 0.9000 & 0.7778 & 0.8372 \\
DenseNet201 & 0.8636 & 0.7955 & 0.8889 & 0.7619 & 0.8000 & 0.8000 & 0.8421 & 0.7805 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here's slightly altered version of your code based on `colortblr`.
Notice, I have loaded `hhline` package to avoid a problem with `\cline`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array,hhline}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\colorlet{greyheader}{Gray!50}                 \colorlet{greybody}{greyheader!30}
\colorlet{greenheader}{LightGreen!60!Olive!60} \colorlet{greenbody}{greenheader!30}
\colorlet{blueheader}{CornflowerBlue!70}       \colorlet{bluebody}{blueheader!30}
\colorlet{yellowheader}{Red!15!Yellow!40}      \colorlet{yellowbody}{yellowheader!30}
\colorlet{orangeheader}{LightSalmon!70}        \colorlet{orangebody}{orangeheader!30}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{-0.5pt}
  \centering
  \caption{Architecture Performances}\label{tab:lab}
  \vspace{3pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|
      >{\columncolor{greybody}}l|
      *{2}{>{\columncolor{greenbody}}X|}
      *{2}{>{\columncolor{bluebody}}X|}
      *{2}{>{\columncolor{yellowbody}}X|}
      *{2}{>{\columncolor{orangebody}}X|}
    }
    \hhline{~|*8{-}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{greenheader}Accuracy}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{blueheader}Precision}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{yellowheader}Recall}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{orangeheader}F1 Scores} \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{greyheader}Architecture
    & \cellcolor{greenheader}TL  & \cellcolor{greenheader}PT
    & \cellcolor{blueheader}TL   & \cellcolor{blueheader}PT
    & \cellcolor{yellowheader}TL & \cellcolor{yellowheader}PT
    & \cellcolor{orangeheader}TL & \cellcolor{orangeheader}PT \\
    \hline
    VGG16       & 0.8182 & 0.7727 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 \\
    VGG19       & 0.7273 & 0.7955 & 0.8000 & 0.7619 & 0.6000 & 0.8000 & 0.6667 & 0.7805 \\
    ResNet50    & 0.8409 & 0.7045 & 0.8824 & 0.7059 & 0.7500 & 0.6000 & 0.8108 & 0.6486 \\
    ResNet152   & 0.8182 & 0.6591 & 0.9286 & 0.6316 & 0.6500 & 0.6000 & 0.7647 & 0.6154 \\
    DenseNet121 & 0.8182 & 0.8409 & 0.8750 & 0.7826 & 0.7000 & 0.9000 & 0.7778 & 0.8372 \\
    DenseNet201 & 0.8636 & 0.7955 & 0.8889 & 0.7619 & 0.8000 & 0.8000 & 0.8421 & 0.7805 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The colors you chose are so much closer to the original than mine!

Comment: They look closer to OP's choice but this is still only cosmetic.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You need several compilations.

You won't see thin white lines, whatever PDF you use, whatever level of zoom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\caption{Architecture Performances}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l*{8}{S[table-format=1.4]}}[corners,vlines]
\CodeBefore
   \cellcolor{gray!30}{2-1}
   \rectanglecolor{gray!15}{3-1}{*-1}
   \rectanglecolor{green!30}{1-2}{2-3}
   \rectanglecolor{green!15}{3-2}{*-3}
   \rectanglecolor{blue!30}{1-4}{2-5}
   \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{3-4}{*-5}
   \rectanglecolor{yellow!30}{1-6}{2-7}
   \rectanglecolor{yellow!15}{3-6}{*-7}
   \rectanglecolor{brown!30}{1-8}{2-9}
   \rectanglecolor{brown!15}{3-8}{*-9}
\Body
   \Hline
    & \Block{1-2}{Accuracy} & & \Block{1-2}{Precision} & & \Block{1-2}{Recall} & & \Block{1-2}{F1 Scores} & \\
   \Hline
   Architecture & {TL} & {PT} & {TL} & {PT} & {TL} & {PT} & {TL} & {PT} \\
   \Hline
   VGG16 & 0.8182 & 0.7727 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 & 0.8000 & 0.7500 \\
   VGG19 & 0.7273 & 0.7955 & 0.8000 & 0.7619 & 0.6000 & 0.8000 & 0.6667 & 0.7805 \\
   ResNet50 & 0.8409 & 0.7045 & 0.8824 & 0.7059 & 0.7500 & 0.6000 & 0.8108 & 0.6486 \\
   ResNet152 & 0.8182 & 0.6591 & 0.9286 & 0.6316 & 0.6500 & 0.6000 & 0.7647 & 0.6154 \\
   DenseNet121 & 0.8182 & 0.8409 & 0.8750 & 0.7826 & 0.7000 & 0.9000 & 0.7778 & 0.8372 \\
   DenseNet201 & 0.8636 & 0.7955 & 0.8889 & 0.7619 & 0.8000 & 0.8000 & 0.8421 & 0.7805 \\
   \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]